# Change Python Class Variable Value

Tags: python

I am extremely new to Python (coming from JavaScript) and I am battling with understanding how to change a value of a class variable. All I am trying to do is to change the age value, and then display the new `msg`. But when I add `Tester.age = 20` it doesn't change my `msg` output. My `msg` output still uses `age = 10`.

How do I change a class variable externally?

```
class ClassTester:
    age = 10
    seconds = age * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
    msg = "You have lived for " + str(seconds) + " seconds."

Tester = ClassTester()

Tester.age = 20
print(Tester.msg)
```

Comment: You're defining them as static (class-level) attributes. Make them object-level by setting them in the constructor.

Comment: `ClassTester.age = 20`

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using properties, so your interface would not change.

```
class ClassTester:
    def __init__(self):
        self._age = 10
        self._msg = "You have lived for {} seconds."
        self._secs = self._seconds(self._age)


    @staticmethod
    def _seconds(age):
        return age * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60


    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age


    @age.setter
    def age(self, v):
        self._age = v
        self._secs = self._seconds(v)


    @property
    def msg(self):
        return self._msg.format(self._secs)

Tester = ClassTester()

print(Tester.msg) # You have lived for 315360000 seconds.
Tester.age = 20
print(Tester.msg) # You have lived for 630720000 seconds.
```

**EDIT:**
I added a static method to recalculate the seconds value and call that from the `__init__` and the age setter to reduce recalculations as per the OP's concern about those in the comment to another answer

Comment: The only thing necessary to be a property is `msg`. `age` can be a regular attribute, but there's nothing wrong with keeping it as a property as well.

Comment: @abccd That's basically right. I had the recalc of the seconds value inside the age.setter however, and I will bring it back since the OP was concerned about recalculating with every call to msg in a comment to the other answer.

Answer (score 1):

age is the static class variable 
You can directly access the age variable using Class name

```
>>ClassTester.age=20

>>ClassTester.age
>>20
```

[Static class variables in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68645/static-class-variables-in-python)

Comment: I would like to have the age variable non-static though. Which is what I need to learn of course, sorry I am very new to this

Comment: but there is no key word for that you can have than self.age initialized

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to set the variables in an object-level (not class-level). You do this by creating the variables inside the init area like below. You can then change the values externally.

Then you need to calculate whatever you want in a different function, using that variable. Then just call that function where you need it.

VERY IMPORTANT (the mistake I made): The init is written with TWO underscores _ x 2 on each side

```
class ClassTester:
    def __init__(self):
        self.age = 10

    def msg(self):
        self.seconds = self.age * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
        self.txt = "You have lived for " + str(self.seconds) + " seconds."
        return self.txt

Tester = ClassTester()

Tester.age = 20
print(Tester.msg())
Tester.age = 30
print(Tester.msg())
```

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it wrong,
you define `msg` var as an attribute to the class, and it has been evaluated once, (when you instance the class) and no more change,

so when you call:

```
print(Tester.msg)
```

you are getting the first value,

what actully is nearest to your work is just make `msg` into method, simply:

```
class ClassTester:
    age = 10
    seconds = self.age * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
    msg = "You have lived for " + str(seconds) + " seconds."
    def get_msg(self):
        seconds = self.age * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60
        self.msg = "You have lived for " + str(seconds) + " seconds."

Tester = ClassTester()

Tester.age = 20
Tester.get_msg()
print(Tester.msg)
```

Comment: I understand the answer but I don't feel like this is efficient. Now I have to recalculate before using msg again. In javascript the recalculation wouldn't be necessary

Comment: @Frank How would you get an updated value without re-calculating ?

Comment: @Frank , the thing that there's no **Closure** in python ,

Answer (score 0):

First, as was pointed out in comments, you should declare variables in `__init__` constructor. As to your example, I'd suggest to make some more advanced steps, so consider following: you actually have only one *important* variable, which is `self.age`. Everything else is derived from it, and so you can lose consistency: for example, when changing `self.age` another variables will not be changed. Also, you can later on in your project change `self.seconds` variable, thus completely messing up your class instance. To solve that, have a look at `property` decorator:

```
class ClassTester:
    def __init__(self, age=10):
        self.age = age

    @property
    def seconds(self):
        return self.age * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60

    @property
    def msg(self):
        return "You have lived for {} seconds.".format(self.seconds)
```

There, `@property` is a handy decorator, which allows you to do address `seconds` and `msg` as attributes, but which will be always synced and consistent: first, you cannot set `seconds` attribute, thus it is protected. Second, changing `age` will affect all subsequent calls to `msg` and `seconds`.

Example usage:

```
>>> tester = ClassTester()
>>> tester.seconds
315360000
>>> tester.msg
'You have lived for 315360000 seconds.'
>>> tester.age = 23
>>> tester.seconds
725328000
>>> tester.msg
```

There is a lot more about `@property`, feel free to explore! For example, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17330160/how-does-the-property-decorator-work) for some in-depth `@property` analysis.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but still deserves a new answer.

It seems that what the OP wanted was to somehow change the value of a class variable in a way that the change could be felt by all objects of the class.

You can´t do it directly changing the value of the class variable, but if the value of the class variable is a mutable object then you can change the content of that object instead and the change will be seem by all instances of the class.

```
class A:
    my_magic = dict()

a = A()
b = A()
c = A()

a.my_magic['x'] = "something"
b.my_magic['y'] = "other thing"

print(c.my_magic)

results

{'x': 'something', 'y': 'other thing'}
```